# How to get a reference to a form that's inside a div#login?

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, mechanize

If I scrape a page like this:

```
<div id="login">
  <form action="http://example.com/" method="post">
  ...
  </form>
</div>
```

How do I get a reference to this particular form?

I think I could search by the action attribute `agent.page.form_with(:action = 'http://example.com/')`, but what if there are two different forms with the same `action` attribute, and the one that I want is inside a `<div id="login">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
page.form_with :form_node => page.at('#login form')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also count forms on the page.  For instance, if that is the first form on the page:

```
form = agent.page.forms[0]
p form

--output:--
#<Mechanize::Form
....
```